# How to build wheel files with CUDA support?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, object-detection, python-wheel, semantic-segmentation

How do I create .whl wheel file with CUDA support? I have a fork of facebook's detectron2 project and I have made some changes. Now I would like to build the project. When I run this command: `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, it creates a wheel file with the name: `projectname-0.1.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl`. However, when I check the official wheels website of facebook's detectron2, the wheel files have a unique naming convention i.e. `detectron2-0.1.3+cu102-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl`. Here you can see that the project was built with CUDA10.2 capabilities. I assume my project's wheel files are built to be run only on the CPU. How can I achieve the same? Or am I wrong in my assumption?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`detectron2` [includes the suffix in the version](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/de098423c675dad38c23110407926ccf2919474d/setup.py#L25). I.e., the version is not `0.1.3` but `0.1.3+cu102`.